# Executing rake tasks on an exploded war on tomcat without jruby being installed

Tags: jruby, warbler

My rails project is deployed to tomcat with the help of warbler, but I need to be able to run rake tasks on that server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stay tuned. I hope to have this capability in Warbler 1.4. Jake Goulding, a community member, has been doing some great work on this.

Until then, a typical approach would be to ensure all your Rake and database scripts are present in the war file, then just unpack it somewhere, cd to `WEB-INF` inside the unpacked war, and run something like `java -cp lib/jruby-core*.jar:lib/jruby-stdlib*.jar org.jruby.Main -S rake -T`.

Comment: java -cp lib/jruby-core*.jar:lib/jruby-stdlib*.jar org.jruby.Main -S rake -T --trace gets me an error that leads to the line where I include Warbler::Task.new in one of my rake files. Warbler is included in the gems.jar.

Comment: I think I've almost got it. I put the 'Warbler::Task::new' and related code in a separate file and excluded it from the war file.

Comment: I was able to make this a lot easier by putting Nick's logic into a script in the bin directory and deploying that directory with the project. I named the script "tomcat-rake".