# Running Rake Tasks In WAS without JRuby

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, jruby, warbler

Related to : [Executing rake tasks on an exploded war on tomcat without jruby being installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6210222/executing-rake-tasks-on-an-exploded-war-on-tomcat-without-jruby-being-installed)

I'm trying to run rake tasks in my Tomcat server that doesn't have JRuby installed.  I'm using warbler to create a war file.

Using the answer to the linked question, I ran:

```
java -cp lib/jruby-core*.jar:lib/jruby-stdlib*.jar org.jruby.Main -S rake -T
```

This gets me the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jruby/Main
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jruby.Main
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
```

`ls lib` gets me:

```
ems-gems-activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.2.2-lib-arjdbc-jdbc-adapter_java.jar
gems-gems-jdbc-sqlite3-3.7.2-lib-sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2.jar
gems-gems-jruby-jars-1.6.8-lib-jruby-core-1.6.8.jar
gems-gems-jruby-jars-1.6.8-lib-jruby-stdlib-1.6.8.jar
gems-gems-jruby-rack-1.1.10-lib-jruby-rack-1.1.10.jar
gems-gems-json-1.7.5-java-lib-json-ext-generator.jar
gems-gems-json-1.7.5-java-lib-json-ext-parser.jar
gems-gems-therubyrhino_jar-1.7.4-jar-rhino-1.7R4.jar
gems-gems-warbler-1.3.6-lib-warbler_jar.jar
jruby-core-1.6.8.jar
jruby-rack-1.1.10.jar
jruby-stdlib-1.6.8.jar
ojdbc6.jar
```

Opening up the `jruby-core-1.6.8.jar` file, I can see that there is indeed a `org/jruby/Main.class` file.

As one can see from the file listing, there is no `jruby-complete` jar file, so I can't run the command from https://stackoverflow.com/a/9982556/684934

What am I doing wrong, and is there by now a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I was working on a similar problem 2 months ago, so things may have changed, but I needed to include all the jars in my class path, had to use bin stubs, and had to set GEM_HOME to get everything working. It may have been simpler, but the posts you referenced didn't work for me either.

I actually had jruby installed, (but I was only using it to build the concatenated class path), so my setup was something like:

```
cd /path/to/application/
export GEM_HOME=/path/to/application/gems
export CLASSPATH=$(jruby -e 'puts Dir["lib/*.jar"].join(":")')

RAILS_ENV=production java -cp $CLASSPATH org.jruby.Main bin/rake -T
```

Also useful, the [jruby-jars](https://rubygems.org/gems/jruby-jars) gem can be included in your gemfile to set the version of jruby that warbler includes (I was using `gem 'jruby-jars', '1.7.0.preview2'` as 1.7.0 wasn't released yet)